# heavy Weight SQL inserts (SqlBulkCopy alternative) without the use of Stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, table-valued-parameters

as i was testing `SqlBulkCopy` at first, it was a preferable way to avoid
 the multiple round-trips with loop of generated inserts From C# to SQL server/
but then i have discovered the user-defined table types `Table-value parameter`
, which was the faster approach, though when working without a stored procedure,
either when simply there was non SP object created on server or when working with `SQL CE` that does not support stored procedures, will the `Table-value parameter` be the best option, can you implement a `DbStuctured` Type SQL parameter without the use of stored procedure and will this be the fastest way to alter data base with mass records (>10000)?

```
select * from @DbStructuredPar into @TargetTableStr
```

Comment: there is a faster way of doing this using tmp tables and XML but I see you don't want to use stored procedures.. is there a reason why you don't want to or can't use stored procedures..

Comment: @MethodMan no , just when working with  local  Db or any reason that no stored procedure is around (planning on a stand alone app version)